# Share a folder using management class in c# vs2010 windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, directory, share

I need to share a folder programmatically in VS2010 using C# on a machine running windows8. there were many solutions on the net out of which i used the one described used Managementclass. It didnt work on my machine. I think for windows 8 the process might be little bit different. I'm trying to figure out whats the problem in my code, till then if I cud get some help, much time will be saved. The code returns an access denied error. Please Help!!!

This is the code I'm using:

ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");

```
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

        ManagementBaseObject outParams;



        inParams["Description"] = "Dump";

        inParams["Name"] = "Dump";

        inParams["Path"] = "D:\\Dump";

        inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Dump");
        if (d.Exists)
        {

        }


        outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

        // Check to see if the method invocation was successful

        if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
        {

            throw new Exception("Unable to share directory.");

        }
```

}